# How do I remove text from before a certain line in delphi

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-7

`<h1 class="tt">example</h1></div><div class="bl_la_main"><div class="divtext">`

I am trying to remove everything before `<div class="bl_la_main">` but keep everything after it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Let `S` be your long string and `Part` your short string. Then try `Copy(S, Pos(Part, S))` or `Copy(S, Pos(Part, S) + Length(Part))`.

Comment: This can end badly. Html isn't line oriented. Don't be surprised if your program is brittle. Consider using a parser. In an ideal world you'd not be using delphi at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**P.S: Since I misunderstood the question, I first created the "take the before terms" function.**

You can take it like this.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 HTML: string;
begin
 HTML := '<h1 class="tt">example</h1></div><div class="bl_la_main"><div class="divtext">';
 Delete(HTML, Pos('<div class="bl_la_main">', HTML) - 1, Length(HTML) - Pos('<div class="bl_la_main">', HTML));
 ShowMessage(HTML);
end;
```

If we need to make it functional;

```
function parseHTML(html: string; substr: string): string;
begin
 Delete(HTML, Pos(substr, HTML) - 1, Length(HTML) - Pos(substr, HTML));
 Result := HTML;
end;
```

Use:

```
function parseHTML(html: string; substr: string): string;
begin
 Delete(HTML, Pos(substr, HTML) - 1, Length(HTML) - Pos(substr, HTML));
 Result := HTML;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 HTML: string;
begin
 HTML := '<h1 class="tt">example</h1></div><div class="bl_la_main"><div class="divtext">';
 ShowMessage(parseHTML(HTML, '<div class="bl_la_main">'));
end;
```

Result:

```
<h1 class="tt">example</h1></div">
```

I created it separately, in a functional way to take both before and after.

```
function parseHTMLAfter(html: string; substr: string): string;
begin
 Delete(HTML, Pos(substr, HTML) - 1, Length(HTML) - Pos(substr, HTML));
 Result := HTML;
end;

function parseHTMLBefore(html: string; substr: string): string;
begin
 Delete(HTML, 1, Pos(substr ,html) - 1);
 Result := HTML;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 HTML: string;
begin
 HTML := '<h1 class="tt">example</h1></div><div class="bl_la_main"><div class="divtext">';
 ShowMessage(parseHTMLBefore(HTML, '<div class="bl_la_main">'));
end;
```

Result:

```
 <div class="bl_la_main"><div class="divtext">
```